# $P(X>Y)$ for $X$, $Y$ not necessarily independent

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian

I am interested in deriving an expression for the probability of a value $X$ being larger than a value $Y$. More specifically: I want to calculate an expression for $P(X>Y|I)$ and I know the probability densities $P(X|I)$ and $P(Y|I)$. The $I$ is some background knowledge I have concerning both variables.

Let us assume that $X$, $Y$ are real-valued and absolutely continuous values in $(x_{min},x_{max})$ and $(y_{min},y_{max})$ respectively. The intervals might be infinite,but do not have to be. Here is what I arrived at (steps shown at the end of the question):

$$P(X>Y|I) = \int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}} dX \, P(X|I) \int_{y_{min}}^{\min(X,y_{max})} dY \, P(Y|X,I)$$

where the comma (,) notation means a *logical and*.

**My questions**

- Is this expression correct?
- What other assumptions about my $X$,$Y$ have I made that I am unaware of?

**Calculation**
To arrive at the expression I wrote

\begin{eqnarray}P(X>Y|I) &=& \int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}} dX \int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}} dY \, P(X>Y,X,Y|I) \\
&=& \int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}} dX \, \int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}} dY P(X>Y|X,Y,I)\cdot P(Y|X,I)\cdot P(X|I)
\end{eqnarray}
and now I can write $P(X>Y|X,Y,I)=\theta(X-Y)$ where $\theta$ is the step function. From this follows:

$$P(X>Y|I) = \int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}} dX \, P(X|I) \int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}} dY \, P(X|I) \cdot \theta(X-Y)\cdot P(Y|X,I) $$

Using the $\theta$ function to constrain the upper integration border, the expression above should follow... I hope.

**Notes: Related Question on math/SE**

I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261073/finding-probability-pxy/261078) related question on math/SE but I am specifically interested in an expression where $X$,$Y$ need not be independent.

Comment: When it comes to your first question ("Is this expression correct?"), I would say yes.

Answer (score 1):

If the random variables (conditional) are not necessarily independent, but you know their marginals (conditional on I), you can try to model them using a copula. This has been studied in a Bayesian context in:

[Bayesian Inference for $P(X<Y)$ Using Asymmetric Dependent Distributions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1362406651)